# How to manipulate tensors distributed across multiple devices in heat

Tags: python

Follow the distributed tutorials, code like that:

```py
import heat

N = 2**10
a=heat.arange(N,dtype=heat.float32,device='gpu',split=0)
a_0=heat.arange(int(N/2),device='gpu',split=0,dtype=heat.int64)
a_1=int(N/2)+a_0

a[a_0] = a[a_1] + a[a_0]
a[a_1] = a[a_0] - a[a_1]
```

When it uses only one GPU, it works fine, but when there are multiple GPUs, it reports an error:

```
File "report_bug.py", line 8, in <module>
    a[a_0] = a[a_1] + a[a_0]
RuntimeError: shape mismatch: value tensor of shape [0] cannot be broadcast to indexing result of shape [512]
```

So i want to know if i operate it in a wrong way or some manual to reference.

Answer (score 0):

When using multi-GPU, the batch index is splitted across multiple GPUs. In order to perform tensor operations as a whole, you should gather them together and perform it like this:

```py
import heat as ht

N = 2**10 
a = ht.arange(N, dtype=ht.float32, device='gpu', split=0)
a_0 = ht.arange (int (N/2), device='gpu', split=0, dtype=ht.int64) 
a_1 = int(N/2) + a_0

# gather tensors from all nodes
all_a = ht.comm.allgather (a)

# manipulate tensors locally
all_a[a_0] = all_a[a_1] + all_a[a_0] 
all_a[a_1] = all_a[a_0] - all_a[a_1]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! so i want to know if there exist some way to manipulate them in multi devices direct, not gather these tensors ?

Comment: i use you steps, but the result turn to that:
    all_a = heat.comm.allgather(a)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1595, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.allgather
    all_a = heat.comm.allgather(a)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1595, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.allgather
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 862, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_allgather
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 145, in mpi4py.MPI.pickle_dump
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 131, in mpi4py.MPI.cdumps
TypeError: cannot pickle 'mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm' object